# moxy: what is the equivalent of RuntimeTypeInfoSet

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

In jaxb-impl, I can get a RuntimeTypeInfoSet object which can be used to map from the xml metadata to the appropriate java reflection data. What is the equivalent for moxy.

UPDATE: my use case is finding a property that maps to an element name. I can of course do it by using java reflection, but it is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)** does not have a direct equivalent to the following class:

- `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeTypeInfoSet`

It appears the purpose of that class is to provide a means to introspect the JAXB mapping metadata for a particular model.  I have opened the following enhancement request for the addition of this feature to MOXy.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/375953

There is set of native objects (`Project`, `Descriptor`,  and `Mapping`) that MOXy holds onto underneath the covers to represent the metadata.  If you can expand your question to indicate what you are looking for I can help you find it.

---

**UPDATE**

> UPDATE: my use case is finding a property that maps to an element
>   name. I can of course do it by using java reflection, but it is
>   cumbersome.

I apologize for the delay in responding. I hadn't noticed that your question was updated with more information:

**Customer**

We'll use the class and get the property name corresponding to the `last-name` element.

```
package forum9992419;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @XmlElement(name="first-name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="last-name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9992419;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBHelper;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLField;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        AbstractSession session = JAXBHelper.getJAXBContext(jc).getXMLContext().getSession(Customer.class);
        ClassDescriptor descriptor = session.getClassDescriptor(Customer.class);
        XMLField xmlField = new XMLField("last-name/text()");
        DatabaseMapping mapping = descriptor.getObjectBuilder().getMappingForField(xmlField);
        System.out.println(mapping.getAttributeName());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
lastName
```